# Double an instance of a Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, double, stub

I am using **Ruby on Rails** with *some hardware which is not available on my development machine*.

Using `Rails.env` I want to **"double" an instance of a class** so that the "real implementation" isn't called (~`double class XY iff Rails.env == :production`).

I have tried rspec-mocks's `double`, but it needs expectations and throws exceptions otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the following code:

```
class Double
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
        puts "#{m} was called with arguments: #{args.join(', ')}"
    end
end
```

Of course this does not work for methods which are declared on `Object`, but it was sufficient for my needs. Also it does not give the ability to pass in parameters.

Furthermore I wrote a little helper function to instantiate objects based on class constants. Since there were some singletons in my code I also implemented a check for that. This way the real classes are only instantiated when the rails environment is 'production'.

```
def instance_of(c)
    if Rails.env == 'production'
        if c.ancestors.include? Singleton
            c.instance
        else
            c.new
        end
    else
        Double.new
    end
end
```

Example usage: `SOME_CONST = instance_of ModuleXY::ClassZ`.